# What would be the authorization workflow for multiple applications with the same authentication web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have two applications, one written in VB.Net using Asp.Net Web Forms (app1). The second is in C# using Asp.Net Core MVC (app2). I want to create a web API that authenticates a user trying to access either app and shares that authorization token between the apps. If the user goes from app1 to app2, the JWT token will be deemed valid and that user will effectively be logged on. If the same user signs out at any point, it removes the JWT token and will require a login again.

I have built a web api that runs with identity and entity framework that already creates JWT tokens if you have an account in identity and successfully performs authorization in itself. I am struggling with getting app2 to accept that JWT and somehow dissect it to see what roles the user has in app2. Here is my current Startup.cs page with how I've wired the JwtBearer:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var authManager = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationManager");
            var key = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(authManager.GetSection("AudienceSecret").Value);
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        options.Authority = authManager.GetSection("Address").Value;
                        options.Audience = "my secret audience";
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                            ValidateIssuer = false
                        };
                    });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
   }
```

Is there a smart way to redirect for login and have app2's controller actions have my [Authorize] attribute just look at the JWT from the API?
Thanks!

Comment: are the websites on different urls? Are they web apps or APIs?

Comment: you could create a gateway API that works as a single entry point, requests are then authenticated from your gateway API and passed through to the relevant API if authenticated

Comment: the websites would be on different urls @joey. They are web apps that would call the authentication API endpoints

Comment: So the 2 web apps are calling a single api, a web api? Is that your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider something like IdentityServer for this.  It can handle these sorts of scenarios out of box -- it's a pretty well-proven .Net solution with extensive documentation and sample code.  https://identityserver.io/